# Regular expression for textbox on the onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, regex

I have not yet mastered the syntax of regexp and I need a regular expression for the keyup event of a textbox that can validate this abstract pattern:

```
d1d2/d3d4
```

*d1*: A number either 0 or 1

*d2*: A number

(d1d2) form a month

the '/' is the separator

*d3*: A number

*d4*: A number

(d3d4) form a year with 2 digits i.e. 12 -> 2012

Can any one make a smart regexp for that validation?

Thanks

Comment: [Here is an excellent tutorial to master the syntax of regular expressions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Although you can do this with a regular expression, isn't it a better idea to convert it to a nummer and check if it'se between 1 and 12 for months and 1900 and 2100 for years?

Comment: And then have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464166/regex-for-credit-card-expiration-date). It should be quite straight-forward to adjust this to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
/^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\/[0-9][0-9]$/
```

Comment: Don't you mean /(?:[01][1-9]|1[12])\/[0-9][0-9]/

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser: `19` isn't a valid month :-P

Comment: Why a non-capture group (`?:`)?  What about the month: `10`?  Why not just `/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}/`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Re: `10`: whoops, duh, fixed, thanks. Re: non-capture group: because I'm only looking to group, not capture. (I treat `(?:...)` as the default, and only use `(...)` when that is actually what I want.)

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh, I see it now.  I thought the first set was days, but now that I look the OP didn't ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/\d{2}$
```